# Question Regarding Proof Using Quadratic Formula

Tags: proof-explanation, quadratics

I'm learning proof techniques. I'm following this PDF at: http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/turnerw/Writing/proofs.pdf

On the Theorem $4$ example (pg. 7), I am confused!

I see that we assume $x \gt 0$ by using the negative (or minus) version of the quadratic formula.

But, there are three things I don't understand.

1. Why is $\frac{2a - 2b} { 2a}$ simplified into $1 - (\frac{b}{a})$? When I simplify this equation, I get $\frac{(a-b)}{a}$.
2. Why is the value of b important, or is it not? $b = a(1 − x)$
3. And where it's stated at the bottom that a divides b, is that referring to the equation $x = 1 - (\frac{b}{a})$?

Thank you for the help.

Update:
Thank you to Eevee for the answer. I still have one more question which is -- why do we choose the negative (or minus) quadratic formula for when x > 0? I had sort of inferred that we did because otherwise x would be negative. But I'm not sure.

Update:
Thank you Sten for the answer. On that note, was it assumed that I would have worked the quadratic formula out both ways? I don't see anything that infers that I would choose the negative (or minus) version of the formula.

Comment: Re your update: If you picked the other branch, you'd get $x = \frac{-b + (b - 2a)}{2a} = \frac{-2a}{2a} = -1$, which is definitely not a positive integer.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I wasn't sure if it was expected of me to work out the solution  on both positive and negative terms, or if that decision was made or inferred elsewhere in the proof. But that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: On that note, was it assumed that I would have worked the quadratic formula out both ways? I don't see anything that infers that I would choose the negative (or minus) version of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that we assume x > 0 by using the negative (or minus) version of the quadratic formula.

No, we assume $x$ is a positive integer from the very beginning. The goal is a proof by contrapositive:

- **What we wish to prove:** *"If $a$ does not divide $b$ then $ax^2 + bx + b - a = 0$ has no positive integer solution $x$."
- **The equivalent contrapositive:** If $x$ is a positive integer solution to $ax^2 + bx + b - a = 0$, then $a$ divides $b$.

Notice that, since we're proving the latter, we want to start with the hypothesis of $x$ being a positive integer solution to the quadratic.

---

> Why is 2a - 2b / 2a simplified into 1 - (b/a)? When I simplify this equation, I get (a-b)/a.

Split up the fraction:

$$\frac{a-b}{a} = \frac a a - \frac b a = 1 - \frac b a$$

---

> Why is the value of b important, or is it not? b = a(1 − x)

The definition of "$p$ divides $q$" is that "there exists an integer $k$ such that $q = pk$." If the goal is to show that $a$ divides $b$, then $1-x$ is that integer (since the proof also assumes $a,b,x$ are integers).

---

> And where it's stated at the bottom that a divides b, is that referring to the equation x = 1 - (b/a)?

It refers, more precisely, to the fact that $b = a(1-x)$, i.e. $b$ is an integer multiple of $a$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the breakdown! I really appreciate it.

Comment: One more question, why do we choose the negative (or minus) quadratic formula for when x > 0?

Comment: Observe that, if we take the positive root, then

$$x = \frac{-b + (b-2a)}{2a} = \frac{-2a}{2a} = -1$$

The problem with this is that it doesn't let you conclude anything about whether $a$ divides $b$ or not.